# Change color of ggplot summary statistic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the color connecting the means in the following box-plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
box.df<-data.frame(myyear=rep(c(2012:2014),each=120),
                   mymonth=rep((1:12),times=10),
                   val=rnorm(120,4,1))
box.df$yyyymm<-box.df$myyear*100+box.df$mymonth
box.df$myyearnr<-as.numeric(as.factor(box.df$myyear))

p<-ggplot(box.df,aes(factor(yyyymm),val))+geom_boxplot()+aes(fill=factor(myyear))
p+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",aes(group=1,colour="yellow"))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",aes(colour="yellow"))
```

.. the plot works in principle, but the connecting line is purple, not yellow.
How can I rectify this?

Thx&kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour is not an aesthetic in this case, so just specify it separately...

```
p+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",aes(group=1),colour="yellow")+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",colour="yellow")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a problem of `aes`. This code works as you want:

```
       library(ggplot2)
       box.df<-data.frame(myyear=rep(c(2012:2014),each=120),
                          mymonth=rep((1:12),times=10),
                          val=rnorm(120,4,1))
    box.df$yyyymm<-box.df$myyear*100+box.df$mymonth
    box.df$myyearnr<-as.numeric(as.factor(box.df$myyear))

       p<-ggplot(box.df, aes(factor(yyyymm), val)) +
          geom_boxplot()+aes(fill=factor(myyear))
    p+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+
      stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",aes(group=myyear),color="yellow")+
      stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",color="yellow")
```